# Why does the UIBarButtonItem not show up when I create it with code?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

When I create a UIBarButton programatically in the viewDidLoad() method it does not show up when I run the program. I am not sure what is happening. Sorry I am new to xcode and do not understand how everything works.

```
var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // creating the refresh control object
    menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Menu", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

}

It should create a UIBarButton in the navigation controller, instead there is nothing there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton`